# Phonegap 3.3 iOS7 external links

Tags: ios, cordova, ios7, phonegap-build

I cant get any external links to show on iOS 7 with Phonegap 3.3, using Phonegap Build

I have this in my config.xml:

```
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
<param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</feature>

<plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />

 <access origin="*"/>
```

And in my code I have:

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
```

And Im launching the link like this:

```
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-a ui-btn-inline" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_system', 'location=yes');"/>Visit Website</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have resolved this with by adding this to config.xml:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
```

And also made this change (not sure that this made any difference):

```
<access origin="*" browserOnly="true"/>
```

And also included cordova.js in the html file instead of phonegap.js

Comment: You don't need the access origin line and you can use phonegap.js.